# Open with Explorer in SharePoint 2013 not working

Tags: 2013, webdav, open-with-explorer

Hi we are currently experiencing error when accessing "Open with Explorer" in DocLib and davWWWRoot on our QA SharePoint 2013 Portal. After 3 log in attempt it show below error:

```
---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
We're having a problem opening this location in File Explorer. Add this web site to your Trusted Sites list and try again.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I already tried below items but nothing works:

1. Re Create new SSL Certificate for https
2. Installed SharePoint Server Foundation SP1
3. Added the Site to trusted Sites List
4. Start/Re Start and Re Install Web Client

Anyone experience this same issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: does it works when:
1. access without https?
2. access from other pc?

Comment: still not working @Eric..

Answer (score -1):

Start the **WebClient** service.You can refer [this](http://algrandi.azurewebsites.net/index.php/sharepoint-2013-error-were-having-a-problem-opening-this-location-in-file-explorer-add-this-web-site-to-your-trusted-sites-list-and-try-again/) for more details

Answer (score -1):

If I disable antivirus it works fine, we use AVG