# Open with Explorer fails when Library contains many files

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, internet-explorer, open-with-explorer

I am using with Internet Explorer 11 (64-bit) to work within certain libraries on a SharePoint Server 2016.

There are a few libraries containing a few 100 files, which I can perfectly access via the "Open with Explorer" button in the browser.

However, there is one library that contains a huge number of files (about 10'000 items), which cannot be opened like this, but the following error message appears after about 10 to 20 seconds:
[image: anonymised error message]
(At first, the Explorer window appears and the progress bar begins to run, but as soon as I confirm the error dialog, the Explorer window becomes closed.)

It seems not to depend on the Windows version, because it is the same on a Windows 7 and on a Windows 10 machine (64-bit both). Also it seems not to be user-dependent, because I am not the only one having this issue.

It is *not* a general access problem (like described in [other](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/121363) [posts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/223806)), because the library was accessible some time ago when there were still a few 1'000 items, and there was no server nor a browser upgrade. Also the [compatibility settings](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/275717) of Internet Explorer (Document emulation mode in the F12 Developer Tools) do not change anything.

The problem even persists when I open a working library in Explorer and try to manoeuvre to the problematic one there.

What causes the described access problem? Is it some kind of timeout error that occurs due to the huge number of items? What can I do to prevent that, what setting do I have to adapt?

Answer (score 0):

Whether all user can not use open with explorer of the library contains many items.

Whether you can use open with explorer in other libraries.

Use IE to open the library. (Open with Explorer will not work with any browser but Internet Explorer)

WebClient Service must be started (Desktop Experience feature enabled for Windows).

Refer to the following article to troubleshoot the issue:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/troubleshoot-issues-using-open-with-explorer

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, it does not really help me, because the trouble-shoot article you shared deals with general access problems, which I am actually not facing. Also it seems to be a general problem, because it is the same for all users I was asking, for the particular library with with 10'000+ items, and all those users can access other libraries with way less items on the same site…